# Azure AD multi-tenant app, Who should be responsible of creating a tenant when a new customer subscribe to the service?

Tags: azure-active-directory

I am reading this docs that talks about security for a multi tenant application. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/multitenant-identity/.

Let's say that my application is **Tailspin**. At least 2 companies, **Contoso** and **Fabrikam**, decide to use my application.

Those are my questions

1. Do I need to create a tenant for each customer that decide to start using my service?
2. Let's say **Fabrikam** already use a provider other than **Azure Active Directory**. If **Fabrikam** wants to use **Tailspin**, am I going force them to create a tenant?

## EDIT

This [short video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7YUTc4Cigc8&t=293s) shows how to start using Slack.

1. The first person to join Slack will enter all the information to **create the space**.
2. After that, that person will enter emails, inviting people to join the organization in Slack.

What I have noticed is that, they invitees don't need to belong to an organization [**tenant**] as they can have **gmail**, **yahoo**, etc. Yet, when user is logged in a space, he/she only sees what's in user's space.

I don't know how slack works, but if you have to implement something similar using Azure Active Directory as Identity provider:

- Are you going to create a tenant for each customer [**you said I shouldn't do that**]
- Should I create a **security group** for each customer that join so that its members can be part of that **group**?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn’t create a separate tenant for these companies. if in case those companies are hosted on different Identity provider. You can federate those Companies identity provider with your application IDP, and you will be accessing the application from their company’s identity itself.

Note: Your application should have capabilities to Federate with other IDP.

You can refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/identity-providershttps:/learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/identity-providers) how to Microsoft federate with other IDP.

**Note**: For multi-Tenant, tenants share physical resources (such as VMs or storage), each tenant gets its own logical instance of the app.

For Single Tenant Architecture where each tenant has a dedicated physical instance

Comment: After watching this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y_wRPk2oKU8 on how to create a space then invite people on Slack, that's actually what I'm looking for. Please check out the edit.